# Convert String to Float in ASP.Net Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, converters

In Asp.Net C# MVC Controller, I want convert from string to float with this code:

```
string test1 = "7.8";
float test2 = float.Parse(test1);
```

The result of test2 is `78` not `7.8`. What should I do to get result `7.8` ?

Comment: Strange thing, I couldn't reproduce your issue. Check the code https://dotnetfiddle.net/uLulIz

Comment: Non-reproducible in VS with other MVC app too. Did you use proper decimal separator?

Comment: Your decimal separator isn't "." It is a "," That's your local enviroment settings. It should work with "7,8"

Comment: I tried to use "7,8" but the result is nol (0) to

Comment: I think test2 = 0 because this line code is not executed, just keep debugging and you will get 7.8

Comment: even float.Parse("7,8") should give the output 78

Comment: you're right Toan Tran, thanks for your correction, so I use "7,8"  and use syntax float test2 = Single.Parse(test1); QBA and then success, thank's

Comment: your comment is correct @Sxntk and solved my problem, you can put in Answer, thanks.

Comment: @AghnatAtqiya nalnpir and Shreyas Pednekar answer is also correct. I prefer the second one because Culture Invariant makes dot is always decimal separator in every enviroment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Sxntk say to me in the comment,

Your decimal separator isn't "." It is a "," That's your local enviroment settings. It should work with "7,8"

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
string test1 = "7.8";    
float test2 = Single.Parse(test1);
```

Please read more : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: the result is nol (0) to

Answer (score 0):

As Sxntk said probably your settings require the , instead of the "." so the solution would be to parse it as another culture like spanish we use the "." instead of the ","

```
float.Parse(test1,new CultureInfo("EN-ES"))
```

you will also need

```
using System.Globalization;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you'll get 7,8

```
string test = "7.8";
float test2 = float.Parse(test, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(test2);
```